# How can I run one gulp function after another in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Here's what I have right now:

```
function make_exHtml(config) {

    gulp.src(config, { base: process.cwd() })
      .pipe(print(function (file) {
          return "Found file " + file;
      }))
      .pipe(rename({ basename: 'base' }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

    return gulp.src(config.srcTemplates)
          .pipe(print(function (file) {
              return "Added file " + file + " to template";
          }))
       .pipe(minifyHTML({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
       .pipe(templateCache({ standalone: true, root: '/app' }))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.destPartials))
       .pipe(gzip(gzip_options))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.destPartials));
}
```

What I need to do is to be sure that the first gulp runs before the second. Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence). Split `make_exHtml` into two tasks

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('make_exHtml', function(callback) {
  runSequence('first_task','second_task', function(){
    make_prod('xxx');
    callback();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's the significance of callback here.  Should I code something for callback ?

Comment: callback is just a function that will run when `runSequence` finishes all tasks. This way gulp would know when `make_exHtml` is done. Argument inside `gulp.task` function is this callback function you need to call when the task is done.

Comment: When first_task and second_task have completed I would like to run the function make_prod('xxx'). Can you show me how I can do this so I can fully understand. Thanks very much.

Comment: I accepted but just one quick question.  If I don't need to do any callback function could I just leave that blank or should I still code in callback()?

Comment: If you don't need callback function you can ommit it, not it's better to pass a callback from the top function so in case you use this task in some other sequence it would work correctly.